# Bash read command with cat and pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin

I have two scripts:

`install.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./internal_install.sh
```

`internal_install.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
while true; do
    read -p "Hello, what's your name? " name
    echo $name
done
```

When I run `./install.sh`, all works as expected:

```
> ./install.sh 
+ true
+ read -p 'Hello, what'\''s your name? ' name
Hello, what's your name? Martin
+ echo Martin
Martin
...
```

However, when I run with `cat ./install.sh | bash`, the `read` function does not block:

```
cat ./install.sh | bash
+ true
+ read -p 'Hello, what'\''s your name? ' name
+ echo

+ true
+ read -p 'Hello, what'\''s your name? ' name
+ echo

...
```

This is just a simplified version of using `curl` which results in the same issue:

```sh
curl -sl https://www.conteso.com/install.sh | bash
```

How can I use `curl`/`cat` to have blocking `read` in the internal script?

Comment: Piping unknown data directly to `bash` is a security risk. Better to save the output of `curl` to a file where you can verify what you've downloaded (visually, comparing its hash to a known hash, etc) before executing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`read` reads from standard input by default. When you use the pipe, standard input is the pipe, not the terminal.

If you want to always read from the terminal, redirect the `read` input to `/dev/tty`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
while true; do
    read -p "Hello, what's your name? " name </dev/tty
    echo $name
done
```

But you could instead solve the problem by giving the script as an argument to `bash` instead of piping.

```
bash ./install.sh
```

When using `curl` to get the script, you can use process substitution:

```
bash <(curl -sl https://www.conteso.com/install.sh)
```